# Formatting decimal number in excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have tables with decimal numbers and i wnat that there will be maximum 2 digits after the point. e.g the number 4.567 will be 4.67, but the number 2 will stay 2, and the number 5.6 will stay 5.6. How can i do that? I managed to do that there will be only two digits, but the number 2 converted to 2.00 and 5.6 to 5.60...

Comment: That isn't called "normalize" -- it's called **rounding**. Check if Excel has a rounding function. (What you tried isn't rounding, but rather it's *formatting*, and that doesn't change the actual value of the number.)

Comment: I want to format the number not to round it, and i dont want to use function. Its should be someting in the cell properties.

Comment: There is no format that displays 2 as `2` and 2.123 as `2.12`.

Comment: Of course there is! Its you need to write someting like "###,###.00"" in the cell properties, but i dont know what.

Comment: Hmm... OK. I'm afraid I can't help, but best of luck!

Comment: I have a solution for this in another thread: [excel number format - varying decimal digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838273/excel-number-format-varying-decimal-digits/40630459#40630459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format Cells->Number->Custom...and enter "0.##"

The "0" means "always displayed" (so in this case a digit before the decimal point). The "#" means "display if present" (so up to two digits after the decimal point). It's not quite perfect as "2" will display as "2.", but I think it's close as you're going to get

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Ed 's answer, if you really want to display whole numbers without the . add a conditional format to the cell using formula (eg for cell A3)

```
=A3-TRUNC(A3,0)=0
```

and apply the general format

Answer (score 0):

Related article: Excel 2007 ROUND Function

The syntax for the ROUND function is:

`= ROUND ( Number, Num_digits )`

> 1.Enter the following data into cell C1: 34.567
>   2.Click on cell D1 in the spreadsheet - this is where the function will be located.
>   3.Type " = round ( " in cell C1.
>   4.Click on cell D1 in the spreadsheet to enter the data in that cell into the formula.
>   5.Type a comma ( , ) followed by the number (one (1) or HOW MUCH YOU WANT) in cell D1 to indicate that the data should be reduced to one decimal place.
>   6.Type the closing bracket " ) " .
>   7.Press the ENTER key on the keyboard.
>   8.The answer 34.6 appears in cell D1.
>   9.If you click on cell D1, the complete function = ROUND ( 34.567 , 1 ) appears in the formula bar above the worksheet.